# Xamarin Forms TabbedPage(s) not showing in Android Preview

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

This should be an easy one... I'm trying to make an extremely simple TabbedPage in Xamarin Forms. Here are the details:

- Using Xamarin Studio Community 6.3 on an Apple with Sierra (10.12.3)
- iOS Preview is displaying tabs fine
- Android Preview is **not** displaying the tabs - only the first child page
- The same thing happens whether using XAML or code
- This is a simple new Xamarin Forms solution, from the initial boilerplate code, without anything else added.

The XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp" x:Class="MyApp.MyAppPage">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <ContentPage Title="#1"><Label>Testing 1</Label></ContentPage>
        <ContentPage Title="#2"><Label>Testing 1234</Label></ContentPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

That's it. Nothing fancy. I've tried using ContentPage, NavigationPage, StackView, etc. within `TabbedPage.Children`. Same result. Preview works on the iOS Preview, but not the Android. What simple thing am I missing?

Comment: Hey, did you ever find the solution to this? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Hi, I hit the same issue yesterday, did you find a solution?  In case not, I created a Xamarin Bugzilla issue for it with a test app to show the problem: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60345